# Unclear about the purpose of using H2O.ai

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to train a neural network with massive amounts of data. I have around 2million rows and 200k columns of data. My data is in a sparse matrix, which I cannot feed into a neural network. I am required to convert it to a dataframe, but the size is too large for me to do that.

Hence, I am trying to convert it to smaller H2O dataframes, and then merge them combine all the small H2O dataframes into one. However, It does not seem to be working. I assumed that H2O could deal with large amounts of data, and so this is something that can be done. But it doesn't seem to be the case.
Can someone tell me what the purpose of H2O is? Is it only about utilizing fast machine learning models that it offers, along with some sort of parallization or is there more to it? Also, is there a way for me to do what I am looking forward to do. Also, when I use H2O with R, am I using R to run Java code in the background
FYI - I am doing all of this in R.

Answer (score 0):

H2O is built to deal with large amounts of data.  Hence, your problem is perfect for h2O-3.  I would suggest you do the following: save your smaller datasets as .csv files into a folder say big_data_folder.  Say you have data1.csv, data2.csv, data3.csv, .... in your /Users/abcde/big_data_folder.  Then, in your R code, you call this:

dataset <- h2o.importFile("/Users/abcde/big_data_folder")

Then, you can call deeplearning algo with the proper parameters.

To save a h2o frame data1, you can do h2o.downloadCSV(data1, "/Users/abcde/big_data_folder/data1.csv") in R.

The reason that the merging does not work is because it is not implemented efficiently and can take up a lot of memory.  Please try my suggestion and let me know if you encounter problems.

Thanks and good luck,
Wendy

Comment: Your last state shows me how to save one csv file as a H2O dataframe. I already know how to do that. But I need to merge all the data together and then train it. Could you elaborate how your solution helps me do so